# HTML table find the column number of <td> which is in <tr> with its <td> included in rowspan

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html for table like this:

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td rowspan="3">01</td>
         <td>02</td>
         <td>03</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>

         <td>05</td>
         <td>06</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>08</td>
         <td>09</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Now using jQuery:

```
rows = $('table')find('tr')
```

The above code will give me all table rows
Now to get first row data:

```
row_columns = $(row[0]).find('td')
```

Now I get row_columns elements as follow:

```
<td rowspan="3">01</td>
<td>02</td>
<td>03</td>
```

Now similarly for second row:

```
row_columns = $(row[1]).find('td')
```

And for this I get:

```
<td>05</td>
<td>06</td>
```

Now What I want to do is to find the second row_columns result's column position. That is 
Position of

```
<td>05</td>
```

is **2** and the position of

```
<td>06</td>
```

is **3** when counting of column is started from 1.

How can i find the position likewise.

Comment: `row_columns = $(row[1]).find('td').eq(0)` and `row_columns = $(row[1]).find('td').eq(1)`

Comment: refre this link: view-source:http://cdn.srccodes.com/c/112013/40/demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that with `$(row[1]).find('td:eq(0)')` or `$(row[1]).find('td:first-child')`

```js
var row = $('table').find('tr');
var row_columns = $(row[1]).find('td:eq(0)');
console.log(row_columns);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">01</td>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>03</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td>05</td>
    <td>06</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>08</td>
    <td>09</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When I do $(row[1]).find('td:eq(0)'), This gives me *<td>* of second column not first one  as first column *<td>* gets merged to **rowspan** it should be empty or something like that.